# Use richtextbox's runs as itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Well to display "dynamic" data an easy way is to use an `ItemsControl` (with, say, a `WrapPanel` as item template).

Now I wish for my application, a rich text box filled with runs is ideal. - The (number & data) of the runs depends on an observable collection in my viewmodel. If I would use a `WrapPanel` instead of a `RichTextBox` the itemscontrol code would look like:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True">
            </WrapPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now I tried using a richtextbox in my usercontrol, the xaml for the usercontrol then looks like:

```
<UserControl x:Class="testit.MyControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testit"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:DispData}">
            <TextBlock>
                <Run Text="{Binding Text}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" IsDocumentEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <FlowDocument>
                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Paragraph IsItemsHost="True">
                            </Paragraph>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                </ItemsControl>
            </FlowDocument>
        </RichTextBox>
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True">
                    </WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

The viewmodel which is bound to the datacontext of the usercontrol is:

```
namespace testit
{
    class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private readonly ObservableCollection<DispData> _data =
            new ObservableCollection<DispData>();
        public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DispData> Data { get; private set; }
        public ViewModel() {
            Data = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<DispData>(_data);
            _data.Add(new DispData("hello"));
            _data.Add(new DispData("world"));
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

This gives a lot of errors with the `RichTextBox` (first error is that `ItemsControl` can't be placed there, but another is that `Paragraph` doesn't have the `IsItemsHost` property. -- I also wish to stress that if I comment out the richtextbox xaml, the xaml for the wrap panel does work: so it's not the bindings or anything that is wrong.

Can a `RichTextBox` even be used with an `ItemsControl` - and if not, how would I fill the content of the textbox in a MVVM fashion?

Comment: The items panel has to be a subclass of `Panel` (`StackPanel`, `WrapPanel`, `Grid`, `Canvas`, etc.). Possibly you could write your own `Panel` subclass that creates a document viewer adds `TextElements` to a `Paragraph` or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check out [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx) on how to write your own items control that is compatible with `FlowDocument` or `RichTextBox`. Code sample can be found at this [location](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/1/0/E10E16E9-6E7C-4444-A9B1-5155A9B09B1D/FlowDocumentApp.zip)

Once you download the controls, update if-else condition in `GenerateContent()` method in `ItemsContent` as following to add support for `Paragraph` and `Inlines`.

```
private void GenerateContent(DataTemplate itemsPanel, DataTemplate itemTemplate, IEnumerable itemsSource)
{

....

    if (panel is Section)
        ((Section)panel).Blocks.Add(Helpers.ConvertToBlock(data, element));
    else if (panel is TableRowGroup)
        ((TableRowGroup)panel).Rows.Add((TableRow)element);
    else if (panel is Paragraph && element is Inline)
        ((Paragraph)panel).Inlines.Add((Inline)element);
    else
        throw new Exception(String.Format("Don't know how to add an instance of {0} to an instance of {1}", element.GetType(), panel.GetType()));
```

And update your XAML to:

```
<RichTextBox IsReadOnly="True" IsDocumentEnabled="True" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <FlowDocument>
        <flowdoc:ItemsContent ItemsSource ItemsSource="{Binding Data}">                
            <flowdoc:ItemsContent.ItemsPanel>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <flowdoc:Fragment>
                        <Paragraph flowdoc:Attached.IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </flowdoc:Fragment>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flowdoc:ItemsContent.ItemsPanel>
            <flowdoc:ItemsContent.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <flowdoc:Fragment>
                        <flowdoc:BindableRun BoundText="{Binding Text}" />
                    </flowdoc:Fragment>
                </DataTemplate>
            </flowdoc:ItemsContent.ItemTemplate>
        </flowdoc:ItemsContent>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

**EDIT - 1**
As @ed-plunkett suggested, sharing relevant code here (in case the external link doesn't work)

- In order to be able to use `Run` in item-template (similar to label or textblock); you will need to extend `Run` to add a bindable property.

  ```
  public class BindableRun : Run
  {
      public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundTextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("BoundText", typeof(string), typeof(BindableRun), new PropertyMetadata(OnBoundTextChanged));

      public BindableRun()
      {
          Helpers.FixupDataContext(this);
      }

      private static void OnBoundTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          ((Run)d).Text = (string)e.NewValue;
      }

      public String BoundText
      {
          get { return (string)GetValue(BoundTextProperty); }
          set { SetValue(BoundTextProperty, value); }
      }
  }
  ```
- Next you would need is the ability to mark a container control as items host; that can be done by defining an attached property.

  ```
  public class Attached
  {
      private static readonly DependencyProperty IsItemsHostProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsItemsHost", typeof(bool), typeof(Attached), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.NotDataBindable, OnIsItemsHostChanged));
      private static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsHostProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemsHost", typeof(FrameworkContentElement), typeof(Attached), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.NotDataBindable));

      public static bool GetIsItemsHost(DependencyObject target)
      {
          return (bool)target.GetValue(IsItemsHostProperty);
      }


      public static void SetIsItemsHost(DependencyObject target, bool value)
      {
          target.SetValue(IsItemsHostProperty, value);
      }


      private static void SetItemsHost(FrameworkContentElement element)
      {
          FrameworkContentElement parent = element;
          while (parent.Parent != null)
              parent = (FrameworkContentElement)parent.Parent;
          parent.SetValue(ItemsHostProperty, element);
      }


      public static FrameworkContentElement GetItemsHost(DependencyObject dp)
      {
          return (FrameworkContentElement)dp.GetValue(ItemsHostProperty);
      }

      private static void OnIsItemsHostChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          if ((bool)e.NewValue)
          {
              FrameworkContentElement element = (FrameworkContentElement)d;
              if (element.IsInitialized)
                  SetItemsHost(element);
              else
                  element.Initialized += ItemsHost_Initialized;
          }
      }

      private static void ItemsHost_Initialized(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          FrameworkContentElement element = (FrameworkContentElement)sender;
          element.Initialized -= ItemsHost_Initialized;
          SetItemsHost(element);
      }
  }
  ```
- A fragment control that you can use to embed `FrameworkContentElement` inside `DataTemplate`.

  ```
  [ContentProperty("Content")]
  public class Fragment : FrameworkElement
  {
      private static readonly DependencyProperty ContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Content", typeof(FrameworkContentElement), typeof(Fragment));

      public FrameworkContentElement Content
      {
          get
          {
              return (FrameworkContentElement)GetValue(ContentProperty);
          }
          set
          {
              SetValue(ContentProperty, value);
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- And, finally the items control itself:, that does the major heavy lifting:

  ```
  public class ItemsContent : Section
  {
      private static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(IEnumerable), typeof(ItemsContent), new PropertyMetadata(OnItemsSourceChanged));
      private static readonly DependencyProperty ItemTemplateProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ItemsContent), new PropertyMetadata(OnItemTemplateChanged));
      private static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsPanelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsPanel", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ItemsContent), new PropertyMetadata(OnItemsPanelChanged));

      public ItemsContent()
      {
          Helpers.FixupDataContext(this);
          Loaded += ItemsContent_Loaded;
      }

      private void ItemsContent_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          GenerateContent(ItemsPanel, ItemTemplate, ItemsSource);
      }

      public IEnumerable ItemsSource
      {
          get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
          set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
      }

      public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
      {
          get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
          set { SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
      }

      public DataTemplate ItemsPanel
      {
          get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemsPanelProperty); }
          set { SetValue(ItemsPanelProperty, value); }
      }

      private void GenerateContent(DataTemplate itemsPanel, DataTemplate itemTemplate, IEnumerable itemsSource)
      {
          Blocks.Clear();
          if (itemTemplate != null && itemsSource != null)
          {
              FrameworkContentElement panel = null;

              foreach (object data in itemsSource)
              {
                  if (panel == null)
                  {
                      if (itemsPanel == null)
                          panel = this;
                      else
                      {
                          FrameworkContentElement p = Helpers.LoadDataTemplate(itemsPanel);
                          if (!(p is Block))
                              throw new Exception("ItemsPanel must be a block element");
                          Blocks.Add((Block)p);
                          panel = Attached.GetItemsHost(p);
                          if (panel == null)
                              throw new Exception("ItemsHost not found. Did you forget to specify Attached.IsItemsHost?");                            
                      }
                  }
                  FrameworkContentElement element = Helpers.LoadDataTemplate(itemTemplate);
                  element.DataContext = data;
                  Helpers.UnFixupDataContext(element);
                  if (panel is Section)
                      ((Section)panel).Blocks.Add(Helpers.ConvertToBlock(data, element));
                  else if (panel is TableRowGroup)
                      ((TableRowGroup)panel).Rows.Add((TableRow)element);
                  else if (panel is Paragraph && element is Inline)
                      ((Paragraph)panel).Inlines.Add((Inline)element);
                  else
                      throw new Exception(String.Format("Don't know how to add an instance of {0} to an instance of {1}", element.GetType(), panel.GetType()));
              }
          }
      }

      private void GenerateContent()
      {
          GenerateContent(ItemsPanel, ItemTemplate, ItemsSource);
      }

      private void OnItemsSourceChanged(IEnumerable newValue)
      {
          if (IsLoaded)
              GenerateContent(ItemsPanel, ItemTemplate, newValue);
      }

      private void OnItemTemplateChanged(DataTemplate newValue)
      {
          if (IsLoaded)
              GenerateContent(ItemsPanel, newValue, ItemsSource);
      }

      private void OnItemsPanelChanged(DataTemplate newValue)
      {
          if (IsLoaded)
              GenerateContent(newValue, ItemTemplate, ItemsSource);
      }

      private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          ((ItemsContent)d).OnItemsSourceChanged((IEnumerable)e.NewValue);
      }

      private static void OnItemTemplateChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          ((ItemsContent)d).OnItemTemplateChanged((DataTemplate)e.NewValue);
      }

      private static void OnItemsPanelChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
      {
          ((ItemsContent)d).OnItemsPanelChanged((DataTemplate)e.NewValue);
      }
  }
  ```
- Static helper methods:

  ```
  internal static class Helpers
  {
      /// <summary>
      /// If you use a bindable flow document element more than once, you may encounter a "Collection was modified" exception.
      /// The error occurs when the binding is updated because of a change to an inherited dependency property. The most common scenario 
      /// is when the inherited DataContext changes. It appears that an inherited properly like DataContext is propagated to its descendants. 
      /// When the enumeration of descendants gets to a BindableXXX, the dependency properties of that element change according to the new 
      /// DataContext, which change the (non-dependency) properties. However, for some reason, changing the flow content invalidates the 
      /// enumeration and raises an exception. 
      /// To work around this, one can either DataContext="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=FrameworkElement}}" 
      /// in code. This is clumsy, so every derived type calls this function instead (which performs the same thing).
      /// See http://code.logos.com/blog/2008/01/data_binding_in_a_flowdocument.html
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="element"></param>
      public static void FixupDataContext(FrameworkContentElement element)
      {
          Binding b = new Binding(FrameworkContentElement.DataContextProperty.Name);
          // another approach (if this one has problems) is to bind to an ancestor by ElementName
          b.RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(FrameworkElement), 1);
          element.SetBinding(FrameworkContentElement.DataContextProperty, b);
      }


      private static bool InternalUnFixupDataContext(DependencyObject dp)
      {
          // only consider those elements for which we've called FixupDataContext(): they all belong to this namespace
          if (dp is FrameworkContentElement && dp.GetType().Namespace == typeof(Helpers).Namespace)
          {
              Binding binding = BindingOperations.GetBinding(dp, FrameworkContentElement.DataContextProperty);
              if (binding != null
                  && binding.Path != null && binding.Path.Path == FrameworkContentElement.DataContextProperty.Name
                  && binding.RelativeSource != null && binding.RelativeSource.Mode == RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor && binding.RelativeSource.AncestorType == typeof(FrameworkElement) && binding.RelativeSource.AncestorLevel == 1)
              {
                  BindingOperations.ClearBinding(dp, FrameworkContentElement.DataContextProperty);
                  return true;
              }
          }
          // as soon as we have disconnected a binding, return. Don't continue the enumeration, since the collection may have changed
          foreach (object child in LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(dp))
              if (child is DependencyObject)
                  if (InternalUnFixupDataContext((DependencyObject)child))
                      return true;
          return false;
      }


      public static void UnFixupDataContext(DependencyObject dp)
      {
          while (InternalUnFixupDataContext(dp))
              ;
      }


      /// <summary>
      /// Convert "data" to a flow document block object. If data is already a block, the return value is data recast.
      /// </summary>
      /// <param name="dataContext">only used when bindable content needs to be created</param>
      /// <param name="data"></param>
      /// <returns></returns>
      public static Block ConvertToBlock(object dataContext, object data)
      {
          if (data is Block)
              return (Block)data;
          else if (data is Inline)
              return new Paragraph((Inline)data);
          else if (data is BindingBase)
          {
              BindableRun run = new BindableRun();
              if (dataContext is BindingBase)
                  run.SetBinding(BindableRun.DataContextProperty, (BindingBase)dataContext);
              else
                  run.DataContext = dataContext;
              run.SetBinding(BindableRun.BoundTextProperty, (BindingBase)data);
              return new Paragraph(run);
          }
          else
          {
              Run run = new Run();
              run.Text = (data == null) ? String.Empty : data.ToString();
              return new Paragraph(run);
          }
      }


      public static FrameworkContentElement LoadDataTemplate(DataTemplate dataTemplate)
      {
          object content = dataTemplate.LoadContent();
          if (content is Fragment)
              return (FrameworkContentElement)((Fragment)content).Content;
          else if (content is TextBlock)
          {
              InlineCollection inlines = ((TextBlock)content).Inlines;
              if (inlines.Count == 1)
                  return inlines.FirstInline;
              else
              {
                  Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
                  // we can't use an enumerator, since adding an inline removes it from its collection
                  while (inlines.FirstInline != null)
                      paragraph.Inlines.Add(inlines.FirstInline);
                  return paragraph;
              }
          }
          else
              throw new Exception("Data template needs to contain a <Fragment> or <TextBlock>");
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: This is great, but we've found that external content usually goes dead in a year or two, so we've got a chronic problem with link-based answers floating around that aren't much use. If there's anything non-obvious in the code you linked, please include it in the answer.

Comment: If I understand you right, you are asking me to share the entire `ItemsContent` source code here?

Comment: Just any parts that aren't obvious. If it's relatively brief, may as well throw in the whole thing.

Comment: @EdPlunkett - I have added the relevant code with some basic explanation.